# nova.conf file is not complete

Tags: 14.04, openstack

I was installing the compute controller components:

```
apt-get install nova-api nova-cert nova-conductor nova-consoleauth nova-novncproxy nova-scheduler python-novaclient
```

This install is successful. But when I check the `nova.conf` file 
it's only 12 lines and the only category is `[default]`.

Why is the complete `nova.conf` file not downloaded?

Comment: yes it could be it's only 12 lines ...  But other configuration files like the /etc/glance/glance-api.conf have many categories like [database] etc...  so I've presumed it should be more complete...

Comment: Good enough as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with a [bare](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openstack/dev/44165#44165) nova.conf and you are expected to add in all the other options.

From the 1st link:

> You would need to add those sections (ie. [database], [glance], and
>   [keystone_authtoken] sections.) , if the docs don't make it clear,
>   please report it as a bug :)

---

> Packages should include at least the upstream example configuration
>   file(s). For some reason, Ubuntu continues to package a very minimal
>   nova.conf file. Please file a bug under the Ubuntu nova package rather
>   than the documentation.

---

And there is indeed a [bug #1415566](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nova/+bug/1415566) outstanding for this so please add yourself.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot everyone.  I'll go ahead and add those categories manually.  No problem then :-)  Thanks !!